# Error after runing installation command for npm

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

After running npm install I have errors that I don't know how to fix. Errors are visible on the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check the internet connection. again it's still on error, check out whether nodejs package contains npm source files or not. if it's not, go to npmjs.com website and download the npm installer package or  reinstall nodejs to latest version..